# Azure Graphi APi List of cloud printers limited by 100 items

Tags: c#, azure, printing, microsoft-graph-api

Getting list of universal printers from Azure by next code:

```
            var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>
            {
                new QueryOption("$top", "300")
            };

            var printerItems = await ApplicationGraphClient.Print.Printers
                .Request(queryOptions)
                .Filter(filter)
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    x.Id,
                    x.DisplayName
                })
                .GetAsync();
```

If I increase above 100 like 300 - it still returns 100 items.  Is this hardcoded for UP API?
If I use 10 - it works - so code is valid.
P.S. I know I can use pagination but I'm interested to increase the page size

Comment: try replacing the $top with $first in the code line of new QueryOption("$top", "300")

Comment: $first gives the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Paging behavior varies across different Microsoft Graph APIs.

- Different APIs might have different default and maximum page sizes.
- Different APIs might behave differently if you specify a page size (via the `$top` query parameter) that exceeds the maximum page size for that API. Depending on the API, the requested page size might be ignored, it might default to the maximum page size for that API, or Microsoft Graph might return an error.

Maximum page size for printing API is 100.